# My self-dividing checking function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm given an array as an input, and I have to reconstruct a new array containing all the integers that are self-dividing (and contains no zeros as a digit). It works properly except with one particular integer, 21.

This is for a coding question. What I tried works perfectly.

```
int IsSelfDividing(int number)
{
    int tmp = number;
    while (tmp > 0)
    {
        tmp %= 10;
        if(tmp == 0 || (number % tmp) > 0)
            return 0;
        tmp /= 10;
    }
    return 1;

    //This approach works, but I don't understand why
    /*
    int x = number;
    while (x > 0) {
        int d = x % 10;
        x /= 10;
        if (d == 0 || (number % d) > 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
    */
}
```

I expect the output to be 0 when I input "21" as an argument to the function IsSelfDividing.

Comment: `tmp %= 10;` will result in `tmp` somewhere in `0...9`. Later, `tmp /=10;` now performs integer division on that `0...9` value with divisor 10, which will *always* result in `0`. Therefore, loop breaks. done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    tmp %= 10;
```

This doesn't work because you're trying to use `tmp` as a single variable to hold two things. Temp now contains the current digit of the number being processed. Lower down, `tmp /= 10;` is waiting for you, expects all remaining digits.

The second version works because it introduces a new variable `d` with `int d = x % 10;` to contain the current digit.